# How to avoid String hardcoding when comparing Java generics?

Tags: java, android, generics, comparison

Is there any better way in which I can compare `Type` to java generic other that hardcoding a `String`?

In this method I would like to swap the hardcoded string for a reference to the class:

```
    @Override
    public Object fromBody(TypedInput body, Type type) throws ConversionException {
        if (!type.toString().equals("com.package.app.LstMdl<com.package.app.AdMdl>")) { //I would like not to use this String
            //do sth
        }
        return super.fromBody(body, type);
    }
```

I tried to swap it for this:

```
        @Override
        public Object fromBody(TypedInput body, Type type) throws ConversionException {
            if (!(type.equals(LstMdl.class) && ((LstMdl)type).data.getClass().equals(AdMdl.class))) {
                //do sth
            }
            return super.fromBody(body, type);
        }
```

but it doesn't work. First solution works fine, but is there any way to do this more elegant?

Comment: shouldn't `type.equals(LstMdl.class)` be `type.getClass().equals(LstMdl.class)`

Comment: @FunkTheMonk doesn't work properly :/

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if (!(type.equals(LstMdl.class) && ((ParameterizedType)type).getActualTypeArguments()[0].equals(AdMdl.class))) {
```

Answer (score 0):

We could try to build the String out of the classes like this:

```
String expectedTypeStr = String.format("%s<%s>", LstMdl.class.getName(), AdMdl.class.getName());
if (!type.toString().equals(expectedTypeStr)) {
```